# Best practices for consistent and comprehensive address storage in a database

Tags: database, standards, modeling

Are there any best practices (or even standards) to store addresses in a consistent and comprehensive way in a database ?

To be more specific, I believe at this stage that there are two cases for address storage :

- you just need to associate an address to a person, a building or any item (the most common case). Then a flat table with text columns (address1, address2, zip, city) is probably enough. This is not the case I'm interested in.
- you want to run statistics on your addresses : how many items in a specific street, or city or... Then you want to avoid misspellings of any sorts, and ensure consistency. My question is about best practices in this specific case : what are the best ways to model a consistent address database ?

A country specific design/solution would be an excellent start.

**ANSWER** : There does not seem to exist a perfect answer to this question yet, but :

- [xAL](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ciq/ciq.html#6), as [suggested by Hank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126207/best-practices-for-consistent-and-comprehensive-address-storage-in-a-database#126219), is the closest thing to a global standard that popped up. It seems to be quite an overkill though, and I am not sure many people would want to implement it in their database...
- To start one's own design (for a specific country), [Dave's link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126207/best-practices-for-consistent-and-comprehensive-address-storage-in-a-database#126860) to the [Universal Postal Union](http://www.upu.int/post_code/en/postal_addressing_systems_member_countries.shtml) (UPU) site is a very good starting point.
- As for France, there is a norm (non official, but de facto standard) for addresses, which bears the lovely name of [AFNOR XP Z10-011](http://www.boutique.afnor.org/NEL5DetailNormeEnLigne.aspx?&nivCtx=NELZNELZ1A10A101A107&ts=1843530&CLE_ART=FA047725) (french only), and has to be paid for. The [UPU](http://www.upu.int/post_code/en/postal_addressing_systems_member_countries.shtml) description for France is based on this norm.
- I happened to find the equivalent norm for Sweden : [SS 613401](http://www.sis.se/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabName=@DocType_1&Doc_ID=34763).
- At European level, some effort has been made, resulting in the norm EN 14142-1. It is obtainable via [CEN national members](http://www.cen.eu/cenorm/members/national+members/members.asp).

Comment: In what country / countries? Address formatting and composition varies a lot between different countries. If you're only dealing with a single country the model can be a lot more simple than if you want to store addresses from any country in a structured way....

Comment: France would be perfect ;-) You are right : single country addresses (US would be the most common, I believe) would be an excellent starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use an `Address` table, as you've suggested, and I'd base it on the data tracked by [xAL](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/ciq/ciq.html#6).

Answer (score 35):

I've been thinking about this myself as well. Here are my loose thoughts so far, and I'm wondering what other people think.

xAL (and its sister that includes personal names, XNAL) is used by both Google and Yahoo's geocoding services, giving it some weight. But since the same address can be described in xAL in many different ways--some more specific than others--then I don't see how xAL itself is an acceptable format for data storage. Some of its field names could be used, however, but in reality the only basic format that can be used among the 16 countries that my company ships to is the following:

```
enum address-fields 
{
    name,
    company-name,
    street-lines[], // up to 4 free-type street lines
    county/sublocality,
    city/town/district,
    state/province/region/territory,
    postal-code,
    country
}
```

That's easy enough to map into a single database table, just allowing for NULLs on most of the columns. And it seems that this is how Amazon and a lot of organizations actually store address data. So the question that remains is how should I model this in an object model that is easily used by programmers and by any GUI code. Do we have a base `Address` type with subclasses for each type of address, such as `AmericanAddress`, `CanadianAddress`, `GermanAddress`, and so forth? Each of these address types would know how to format themselves and optionally would know a little bit about the validation of the fields.

They could also return some type of metadata about each of the fields, such as the following pseudocode data structure:

```
structure address-field-metadata 
{
    field-number,     // corresponds to the enumeration above
    field-index,      // the order in which the field is usually displayed
    field-name,       // a "localized" name; US == "State", CA == "Province", etc
    is-applicable,    // whether or not the field is even looked at / valid
    is-required,      // whether or not the field is required
    validation-regex, // an optional regex to apply against the field
    allowed-values[]  // an optional array of specific values the field can be set to
}
```

In fact, instead of having individual address objects for each country, we could take the slightly less object-oriented approach of having an `Address` object that eschews .NET properties and uses an `AddressStrategy` to determine formatting and validation rules:

```
object address
{
    set-field(field-number, field-value),
    address-strategy
}

object address-strategy
{
    validate-field(field-number, field-value),
    cleanse-address(address),
    format-address(address, formatting-options)
}
```

When setting a field, that `Address` object would invoke the appropriate method on its internal `AddressStrategy` object.

The reason for using a `SetField()` method approach rather than properties with getters and setters is so that it is easier for code to actually set these fields in a generic way without resorting to reflection or switch statements.

You can imagine the process going something like this:

1. GUI code calls a factory method or some such to create an address based on a country. (The country dropdown, then, is the first thing that the customer selects, or has a good guess pre-selected for them based on culture info or IP address.)
2. GUI calls `address.GetMetadata()` or a similar method and receives a list of the `AddressFieldMetadata` structures as described above. It can use this metadata to determine what fields to display (ignoring those with `is-applicable` set to `false`), what to label those fields (using the `field-name` member), display those fields in a particular order, and perform cursory, presentation-level validation on that data (using the `is-required`, `validation-regex`, and `allowed-values` members).
3. GUI calls the `address.SetField()` method using the `field-number` (which corresponds to the enumeration above) and its given values. The `Address` object or its strategy can then perform some advanced address validation on those fields, invoke address cleaners, etc.

There could be slight variations on the above if we want to make the `Address` object itself behave like an immutable object once it is created. (Which I will probably try to do, since the `Address` object is really more like a data structure, and probably will never have any true behavior associated with itself.)

Does any of this make sense? Am I straying too far off of the OOP path? To me, this represents a pretty sensible compromise between being so abstract that implementation is nigh-impossible (xAL) versus being strictly US-biased.

---

**Update 2 years later:** I eventually ended up with a system similar to this and wrote about it at [my defunct blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140322045505/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2010/11/inside-skiviez-mailing-addresses/).

I feel like this solution is the right balance between legacy data and relational data storage, at least for the e-commerce world.

Comment: Your blog link is code 410 "Gone".  Do you have an updated link?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the link to an archived copy

Answer (score 1):

In the UK there is a product called [PAF from Royal Mail](http://www.royalmail.com/portal/rm/jump2?mediaId=400085&catId=400084)

This gives you a unique key per address - there are hoops to jump through, though.

Comment: There are issues with PAF as it only contains addresses to which post is delivered.  The Ordnance Survey equivalent (OSAPR) is in theory superior as it should include all addresses but in practice is error-prone and not updated often. Many local authorities end up using their own in-house system

Answer (score 1):

I basically see 2 choices if you want consistency:

1. Data cleansing
2. Basic data table look ups

Ad 1. I work with the SAS System, and SAS Institute offers a tool for data cleansing - this basically performs some checks and validations on your data, and suggests that "Abram Lincoln Road" and "Abraham Lincoln Road" be merged into the same street. I also think it draws on national data bases containing city-postal code matches and so on.

Ad 2. You build up a multiple choice list (ie basic data), and people adding new entries pick from existing entries in your basic data. In your fact table, you store keys to street names instead of the street names themselves. If you detect a spelling error, you just correct it in your basic data, and all instances are corrected with it, through the key relation.

Note that these options don't rule out each other, you can use both approaches at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, I'd suggest choosing a National Change of Address vendor and model the DB after what they return.

Answer (score 1):

The authorities on how addresses are constructed are generally the postal services, so for a start I would examine the data elements used by the postal services for the major markets you operate in.

See the website of the Universal Postal Union for very specific and detailed information on international postal address formats:http://www.upu.int/post_code/en/postal_addressing_systems_member_countries.shtml

Answer (score 1):

"xAl is the closest thing to a global standard that popped up. It seems to be quite an overkill though, and I am not sure many people would want to implement it in their database..."

This is not a relevant argument. Implementing addresses is not a trivial task if the system needs to be "comprehensive and consistent" (i.e. worldwide). Implementing such a standard is indeed time consuming, but to meet the specified requirement nevertheless mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

normalize your database schema and you'll have the perfect structure for correct consistency. and this is why:
http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/09/17/Normalization-for-databases-is-like-Dependency-Injection-for-code.aspx

Comment: Yes, but do you know of a proven design/normalization for such a database, or does everyone have to reinvent what I believe to be a much commonly needed wheel ?

Comment: well you can google for the address design. but ususally the design depends on your business need. not all of them need athe same model.

Answer (score 0):

I asked something quite similar earlier: [[Dynamic contact information data/design pattern: Is this in any way feasible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80876/dynamic-contact-information-datadesing-pattern-is-this-in-any-way-feasible)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80876/dynamic-contact-information-datadesing-pattern-is-this-in-any-way-feasible).

The short answer: Storing adderres or any kind of contact information in a database is complex. The Extendible Address Language (xAL) link above has some interesting information that is the closest to a standard/best practice that I've come accross...